# Inserir 1000 usuários simultâneos no JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Criei um teste com requisições HTTP, e preciso inserir e fazer login no site com 1000 usuários simultaneamente no JMeter. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mariana, sem conhecer a sua aplicação fica um pouco difícil de detalhar, mas posso fornecer linhas gerais. Creio que a maneira mais prática seja gravar um teste completo usando o JMeter e apenas editar esse teste para o que você precisa.

1) Grave uma navegação no seu site usando o JMeter. Ele permite a criação de um proxy você pode executar as atividades que precisa testar no seu site que o JMeter grava automaticamente no arquivo de teste. Muito bom para evitar um trabalho mais braçal de configuração. Você precisará apenas editar o que ele gravou. Recomendo ler o [Tutorial JMeter: Uso do JMeter para Testes de Desempenho na Web](http://www.decom.ufop.br/imobilis/metodologia-de-testes-tutorial-jmeter-para-testes-de-performance-em-plataforma-web), excelente para ajudar nas configurações

2) Crie alguns ouvintes para registar o teste a ser realizado. Eles permitem a conversão dos dados em gráficos e tabelas para facilitar a visualização. Os seguintes são bem úteis:

- Gráfico Agregado
- Ver Resultados em Tabela
- Ver Árvore de Resultados

3) Configure a carga de teste de que precisa. No primeiro teste, recomendo criar somente 1 thread para validar se o teste que você criou funciona. Caso tenha o resultado desejado, pode aumentar as threads conforme necessário. Recomendo o tutorial [Usando JMeter para testar sua aplicação JSF](http://pt.slideshare.net/jadsonjs/usando-jmeter-para-testar-sua-aplicacao-jsf-39543077) que basicamente faz o que você precisa, mas com JSF.

Basicamente é isso. Mas o JMeter possui configurações mais avançadas, caso seja necessário. Recomendo a leitura também de:

[Destilando JMeter I: Introdução e Conceitos](http://www.bugbang.com.br/destilando-jmeter-i-introducao-e-conceitos/)

[Destilando JMeter II: Vamos escrever testes!](http://www.bugbang.com.br/destilando-jmeter-ii-vamos-escrever-testes/)